# Ho to build a Lucene index in src/main/resources?

Tags: java, indexing, lucene, resources

I'm writing a java program in which I have to build an index with Lucene and then read from it. Eventually, I build a jar with all dependencies because I have to call it from another program from shell.

I'm using Lucene's FSDirectory. Lucene's FSDirectory is useful to read and write index. However, its constructor takes a path as input. [This](http://lucene.apache.org/core/6_6_2/core/org/apache/lucene/store/FSDirectory.html) is the java doc of FSDirectory.

When I usually read a file from resources, I use the following approach:

```
InputStream is = ResourceReader.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("filename.extension");
```

However, as I said above, FSDirectory's constructor requires a Path. But how to give it a path, considered that I'm going to produce a jar?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in one of my project, this solved my problem:

```
FSDirectory luceneIndex = new SimpleFSDirectory(Paths.get("where_you_want_to_store_the_index"));
```

Comment: And what do you put in "where_you_want_to_store_the_index", if it is "src/main/resources" and you have to create a jar?

Comment: If you run a project, using "lucene" will store the index at the root of your project. You can then deploy your application and the index will be stored in a "lucene" directory beside the jar. I think it could work using "src/main/resources", just give it a try. Another possibility is to store the index in the user home directory, so it will not be dependent of the location of your application.